# Conditional expection of some lognormal process

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have the following process

$$y_{t+1} = y_t \exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})$$

where $\varepsilon_{t+1}\sim _{iid} N(\frac{\sigma v^2 }{2},v^2 )$, $v> 0$. I would like to calculate $E[y_{t+1}|y_t]$

For this, I apply conditional expectation in the equation above. So

$$E[y_{t+1} | y_t ] =E [y_t \exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})| y_t] = y_t E [ \exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})| y_t].$$

Now I’m unsure of saying that $\exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})$ and $y_t$ are independent. I suspect this to be true, since $y_t = y_{t-1} \varepsilon_{t} $ and $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ is a iid process. If the independence of  $\exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})$ and $y_t$ is true, I can conclude that

$$E[y_{t+1} | y_t ] =  y_t E [ \exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})| y_t] = y_t E [ \exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})] = y_t \exp( \frac{\sigma v^2 }{2} + \frac{v^2}{2}).$$

Is my argument correct?

Comment: My ignorance?  $E(exp(\epsilon_{t+1}))=\frac{\sigma v^2}{2}+\frac{v^2}{2}$ comes from what?

Comment: If a random variable has a lonormal distribution, $X \sim Lognormal (\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $E(X) =\exp( \mu + \sigma^2/2)$. I have to correct the last equation above. Thanks

Comment: Your argument looks correct.

Comment: So in fact can I say that  $\exp (\varepsilon_{t+1})$ and $y_t$ are independent?

Comment: They are independent.